# Calculation of second-order diagram

Tags: feynman-diagrams, many-body

Can't figure out how to calculate Feynman diagrams of orders higher than one. One of the simplest diagram of second order is:

[image]

Integrating over $q_1$ is not a problem because there is $e^{i\omega\delta}$ factor because of loop:
$$G^{(2)}\sim G(\textbf{p})G(\textbf{p})U(0)n\int G(\textbf{q})G(\textbf{q})U(\textbf{p-q})d^4\textbf{q}$$
$$\textbf{q}=(q,\omega_q)$$
So there is one integral left:
$$\int \left( \frac{\theta (\left\lvert p \right\rvert-\left\lvert p_f \right\rvert)}{\omega_q-\varepsilon(q)+i\delta}+\frac{\theta (\left\lvert p_f \right\rvert-\left\lvert p \right\rvert)}{\omega_q-\varepsilon(q)-i\delta}\right)\left( \frac{\theta (\left\lvert p \right\rvert-\left\lvert p_f \right\rvert)}{\omega_q-\varepsilon(q)+i\delta}+\frac{\theta (\left\lvert p_f \right\rvert-\left\lvert p \right\rvert)}{\omega_q-\varepsilon(q)-i\delta}\right)U(p-q)d^3qd\omega_q$$

And I have no idea on how to proceed. I think I am supposed to integrate over frequency $\omega_q$ first but there is no $e^{i\omega\delta}$ factor like in first order diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the frequency factor, since the integrand decreases faster than $1/|\omega|$ as $|\omega|\rightarrow\infty$. Thus, you can close the contour in either half-plane by an arc of radius $R$ (that you will later take to be infinite), and use the residue theorem.

Note: you do need to open the brackets though, and deal with the four integrals separately. Some of them are zero, since they have poles only in one half-plane.